# Not operator for vim Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to search the following pattern in vim pfxdb.[^.]*

I have tried to escape every combination of special charachters, but it does not seem to be working.

I would have expected one of following two to work.
pfxdb.[^.]*
pfxdb.[\^.]*

Comment: From the `vim` tag `If your question is not about programming, consider posting Vim related questions at the dedicated Vim Stack Exchange site.`

Answer (score 1):

You might try this search pattern `/pdfxdb\.\.\@!\w\+`, but I'm not sure what you really want to achieve.

Explanation to the search pattern:

- `/` Start search.
- `pdfxdb` Search for a specific string.
- `\.` Search for a literal dot.
- `\.\@!` Look ahead and expect everything except a literal dot.
- `\w\+` Search for a word.

This might not be the most efficient solution though.

Comment: _`\.\{0}` Search for a literal dot, but 0 of those_: That's pure nonsense; you can just as well leave it out.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Should've gone with negative lookahead:
`/\w\+\.\.\@!.*`

Answer (score 0):

This worked If anyone has answers within vim, feel free to reply.

grep "pfxdb." XdoData.C | grep -v "pfxdb.."
    " from pfxdb.xdo_instance " <<